# could not retrieve dataframe within iterrows

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to iterate thruogh a dataframe but I dont get any results.

I am reading a csv file with pandas imported.

```
df2 = df1[(df1['col1'] == 'New') ]
for index, row in df2.dropna().iterrows():
    df3 = df1[(df1['col2'] == row['col1'])]
    df3.sort_values(by=['col2'], ascending=False).head(3)
```

If I execute the lines 3 & 4 outside the for loop, I am able to get the results. Any idea why the dataframe is not reading within the for loop?

Comment: you dont have a `print()` in the last line

Comment: yes, that worked. thanks. I thought, the head would print the line but it didnt in jupyter notepad. thanks again

Comment: I'm voting to close this, as the reason why the variables weren't being printed is because there was no print statement.

Comment: As an aside, beware of `iterrows()`. It's somewhat rarely needed, and is notoriously sluggish, amongst other things.